# Battery Life Monitoring App

Tags: android

The length of time it takes for a battery to charge or get consumed varied with the life of the battery.

I am looking for a utility app which gives a clue as to the quality of a mobile phone  battery.

It would record the date and time corresponding to when the cable is plugged or unplugged, together with 'P' or 'U', and the time lag between each of these two successive events, as well as the battery life at these events and every 5 minutes

The app would then display a nice graph correspondibg to the log file data.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely looking for something like **[BatteryBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicator)** (or rather it's [payed Pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro)):

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>*BatteryBot Pro* (source: [Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

- **record the date and time corresponding to when the cable is plugged or unplugged:** Yes (see first screenshot)
- **the time lag between each of these two successive events:** Not directly, as far as I can see; but should be easy to calculate
- **battery life at these events and every 5 minutes:** Yes, again as shown in the screenshot

Additionally, you can see how long your battery charge approximately will hold: in the app, or in the notification area for easier access.

I have not used that app by myself, but a 4.6 rating at > 6.000 votes speaks a clear language to me.

You might as well wish to take a look at **[Kapex Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ck.batterymonitor)**, which gives you the other details you're after:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>*Kapex Battery Monitor* (Source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ck.batterymonitor); click images for larger variants)</sup>

For more alternatives and other candidates, be welcome at my corresponding collection of [Battery Helpers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batteryhelper).